# Rename only unique files

Tags: shell, sh, rename

How to rename only unique files by removing "1" from file name and keep duplicated name files?

*Input:*

```
-english_1.pdf  
-english_2.pdf  
-english_3.pdf  
-mathematics_1.pdf  
-theology_1.pdf  
-economics_1.pdf  
-economics_2.pdf
```

How can I remove the **1** from mathematics_1.pdf and theology_1.pdf with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) or similar?

*Desired output*:

```
-english_1.pdf  
-english_2.pdf  
-english_3.pdf  
-mathematics.pdf  
-theology.pdf  
-economics_1.pdf  
-economics_2.pdf
```

I tried:

```
rename -n  's/1//' *.pdf
```

but it removes *all* the **1**

Comment: The tool for manipulating (creating/destroying/moving) files and processes is shell, not awk. Why do you want to involve awk? [edit] your question to tag it with whatever shell (or non-UNIX environment) you're using so we can help you. Include file names that have `1`s you do NOT want to remove if such exist and show the expected output (it's not clear if you want the `_`s removed too and actually I'm not even sure if what you provided is the sample input or expected output!).

Comment: The problem with `rename` is that there are two versions [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) and [this](https://www.linux.pl/man/index.php?command=rename). Which version do you have? If you have perl-ish rename I think you are pretty close `rename -n 's/_1$//' *.pdf`.

Comment: it seems more versatile than sed and rename, i don't know

Comment: It certainly is but it's a tool for manipulating text, not manipulating files (or processes) - that's what a shell is for. It's extremely unlikely that you'd need some external tool like sed or awk to generate the file names for a job like this. See my first comment for how to get help.

Comment: @KamilCuk  failed! rename V is the 1st

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A safe bet might be the following method:

```
for file in *_1.pdf; do
   [ -f "${file/_1.pdf/_2.pdf}" ] || mv "${file}" "${file/_1.pdf/.pdf}"
done
```

What this does is the following:

- **`for file in *_1.pdf; do ... done`:** make a loop over all files which match the glob pattern `*_1.pdf`. So this matches all files that look like `prefix_1.pdf`
- **`[ -f "${file/_1.pdf/_2.pdf}" ]`:** The first thing we do in the loop is to verify if there exists a similar file with name `prefix_2.pdf`. We obtain this filename with the parameter expansion

  > **`${parameter/pattern/string}`:** Pattern substitution.  The  `pattern`  is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion, Parameter is expanded and the longest match of `pattern` against its value is replaced with `string`.
  >
  > **<sub>source: `man bash`</sub>**

  The `test` command, written as `[ -f filename ]` checks if a file with `filename` exists. See `man test` for more information.
- If the above test is successful, we do nothing. If the above test is unsuccessful, we rename the original file using `mv "${file}" "${file/_1.pdf/.pdf}"`. This conditional combination is achieved using on OR-list:

  > An OR list has the form **`command1 || command2`**. `command2` is executed if, and only if, `command1` returns a non-zero exit status.
  >
  > **<sub>source: `man bash`</sub>**

I'm assuming here that a file `prefix_2.pdf` must exist if `prefix_3.pdf` exists.

You can validate the above by adding `echo` before the `mv` command.

Comment: can you explain more about the  [ -f "${file/_1.pdf/_2.pdf}" ]  meaning of the "/" and  | |

Comment: @KarimBnAbdlaziz I have expanded the answer with all needed information.